# PHP round() returns unexpected value

Tags: php, math, rounding

I have a double value of 2.6647 which I am trying to round mathematically correct to 2 decimal places.

I am expecting a return value of 2.67.

7 (the last decimal place) should round 4 (the second-last decimal place) up to 5, 5 should round 6 (the third-last decimal place) up to 7.

```
$value = 2.6647;
echo round( $value, 2, PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP );
```

But instead I receive 2.66. Why is this happening?

PHP Version is 5.3.28.

Comment: PHP works well. **You** are misunderstanding the `round()` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rounding to `n` decimals is driven by `n+1`th decimal. In this case the third one decimal is 4, so the number is rounded down to `2.66`.

Answer (score 2):

> 47 < 50

So 2.6647 will be rounded off to 2.66 irrespective of the last parameter.

Comment: +1 for "irrespective of the last parameter". OP probably misunderstood the `PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP` option.

Answer (score 0):

You are misunderstanding how `round()` works:

**"7 (the last decimal place) should round 4 (the second-last decimal place) up to 5, 5      should round 6 (the third-last decimal place) up to 7."**

This is incorrect.

`round()` only considers the number following the specified decimal places. So in this case, the 7 is not considered at all. Only the 4 is considered, which, being less than 5, determines that the number is rounded to 2.66.

To get the logic as you specified in the quote above, you would need to do something like this:

```
$value = 2.6647;
$value2 = round( $value, 3, PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP ); // 2.665
echo round( $value2, 2, PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP ); // 2.67
```

which is probably not a very feasible way to do things, but should give a better idea of how `round()` is working.

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look this..

In **round** function

```
echo round(2.6647, 2);  // 2.66
echo round(2.6637, 2);  // 2.66
echo round(2.6657, 2);  // 2.67
echo round(2.6667, 2);  // 2.67
```

If third decimal place is 5 or greater than 5 then one incremented at second position.